# getting error while validating the archive in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to distribute my app for testing purpose and I am getting an error while I tried to validate my archive file.

**automatically managed signing**

[image: error]

This is the error that I got when I select "automatically managed signing" and when I tried to set manually, I got this error "Profile is not an "iOS App Store" profile."

Comment: Can you add more information? Did you setup an application in App Store Connect?

Comment: 1. Check if you created app appropriately in itunesconnect.apple.com 2. Check if you are using the "Team" credentials that has registered and paid 99$.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by a resource file containing diacritics in the filename.

There were an accented letter in a filename.

Maybe it's not related for you, but removing all special characters in resources filenames solved my problem.